# Rails: field_tag with javascript to preview files not working correctly

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a `file_field_tag` inside a rails form with a select file field:

```
<%= file_field_tag "attachments[media_files][]", multiple: true, id: "files" %>
```

And I have an area to preview the images/videos and remove if need be:

```
<span id="result"></span>
```

Everything is working correct but there is only one glitch.... If the images/videos are in separate folders, I have to add the files from one folder first and then from the other folder. But after this process only the second batch of files gets saved.

Here is the javascript for all of the above:

```
window.onload = function(){

    //Check File API support
    if(window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader)
    {
        var filesInput = document.getElementById("files");

        filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event){

            var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
            var output = document.getElementById("result");

            for(var i = 0; i< files.length; i++)
            {
                var file = files[i];

                //Allowed files
                //if (!file.type.match(/.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp4|avi|flv|wmv|mov|tiff|bmp|exif)$/i))
                     //continue;

                var picReader = new FileReader();

                picReader.addEventListener("load",function(event){

                    var picFile = event.target;

                    var span = document.createElement("span");

                    span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', picFile.result, '" title="', picFile.name, '"/><span class="remove_img_preview"></span>'].join('');



                    output.insertBefore(span,null);
                    span.children[1].addEventListener("click", function(event){
                        span.parentNode.removeChild(span);
                    });


                });


                //Read the image
                picReader.readAsDataURL(file);

            }

        });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
        alert("Your browser does not support File API")
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this glitch??

Comment: Hello Dev, Here is copy paste code from your question, It looks like your JS function works https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EOWOPo. 
Can you please load your code in a browser and check that the file_field_tag has the correct HTML ID (the HTML ID might be "attachments[media_files][]")?  In most browsers, you can right-click the element and click "Inspect". This will open up dev tools and take you to the element.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jon, I checked the `file_field_tag` id in a browser and its `id=files`